# Charge pumps operation

Tags: charge-pump

In a course of digital electronics, our Professor wanted to give us just an introduction to charge pumps.
Here the basic topology:

[image]

Then he says that the circuit behaves like a bucket brigade chain: a charge packet is transferred by Vdd to CP1 (when CK' is high), then from CP1 to CP2 (when CK is high), and so on and, finally, from CPN to CS. At each transfer step, the voltage of the charge packet is increased. At each clock cycle, Vout is increased until the steady state is reached.

From a conceptual point of view it is clear to me up to now. But then he calculates the dc voltage gain as follows:

[image]

**Question:** why does he say that "each capacitor CPi is charged to the voltage across the preceding capacitor plus Vck"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the clock is low, the first capacitor is charged up to Vdd, then the switch to Vdd opens, and the clock goes high, the relative voltage of Vdd of the capacitor is then offset by CK, as a higher voltage, the capacitor still had the same amount of charge, that has not changed, but the voltage on its top terminal is now a higher voltage,

Next cycle this voltage is used to charge the next capacitor in the chain, this averages the voltage between the 2 capacitors in a charge (voltage) divider, so initially it would be closer to (Vdd + CK) / 2, but as time goes on and the second capacitor charges up with more cycles, as the next time will be (Vdd + CK) * 3 / 4 (the average of the 2 capacitor voltages), and so on and so on, until you end up with Vdd+CK directly,

Due to this, any kind of output load on a charge pump will cause the output voltage to fall, and the more stages you have, the furthur it falls.